# On Careers 2.0, use relocation information to tailor featured jobs

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I've been working on my Careers profile, and stopped by the homepage. One of the things that I immediately noticed is the "featured jobs" section. Although I had just finished entering a list of US states where I would be willing to relocate, only one of the six jobs listed was in one of those states.

Seems like an easy win to me. I know I'm not willing to move to California under almost any circumstance, so showing me those positions is pretty much useless.

Comment: I can be wrong, but I *think* it already does that... maybe it's just about the right proportion. Or maybe it can't deal with lists of states (Edit: no, it doesn't do that any more. I think it used to, though. This would be nice to have back)

Comment: We still think this is a good idea, but I removed the [meta-tag:status-planned] because "soon...ish" is clearly not very soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Having featured jobs be geo-aware is something on our roadmap.  It's a win for you and it's a win for the advertising company.  Coming soon...ish.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Hey Will, almost year has passed any updates?